# Wait for subscription in constructor of a Service

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my service, I want to wait for until local variable `baseurl` is not initialized before making another http request.

Below is my service code:

```
@Injectable()
export class CoursesService  {
  baseUrl;
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    if(this.baseUrl != undefined){
      this.getJSON().subscribe(data =>
        this.baseUrl=data, 
        error => console.log(error)
      );
    }
}

public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get("assets/apiDetails.json")
                  .map((res:any) => res.json());
}

getCourses(){
  return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+"/courses")
    .map((res:any) => res.json());
  }
}
```

As you can see `getCourses` method uses `baseUrl` variable, so When I will call `getCourses` method , I want to wait until  `baseUrl` is not initialized.

I have tried to use `ngOnInit` but it not get called in `Injectable` type class.

Comment: why dont you call the getCourses from the getJSON result? Or subscribe to the result...

Comment: @eesdil : then I'll have to do it each method, that's why I want result in seprate variable

Comment: Since getCourses depends on `baseUrl`, can you define it as an `Observable<any>` and rewrite the constructor and so `getCourses` subscribe to changes of `baseUrl` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make the `baseUrl` into an `Observable` that you `share()` (so many calls can use the same result - it's making the observable [**hot**](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339)) and use in your other calls. Something like this should work:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap'
// ...

@Injectable()
export class CoursesService {
  baseUrl$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
      this.baseUrl$ =
          this.getJSON()
              .share()
  }

  public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get("assets/apiDetails.json")
         .map((res: any) => res.json());
  }

  getCourses(): Observable<YourCourseType[]> {
      return this.baseUrl$
          .mergeMap(url => {
              return this.http.get(url + "/courses")
                  .map((res: any) => res.json());
          });
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll suggest as well to add a `$` at the end of `baseUrl` so that you wont get confused about who's an observables and who isnt

Comment: @QuentinLaillé yep, definitly best practices- updated my answer

Comment: @lexith - no, `share()` is used to store the result. It will only go the the data source once

Comment: @lexith can we add a `publishLast()` from rxjs in this case ?

Comment: But `getJSON` will get called for each request. Once it is initialized, Then I want to use previous value.

Comment: Please see what `share()` is doing.. I gave a link on the subject too @AmitKumar

Comment: @FredrikLundin " i'm getting this error `this.getJSON(...).share is not a function`

Comment: @AmitKumar See updated answer - you need to `import 'rxjs/add/operator/share'`

Comment: @AmitKumar same for `map` and `mergeMap`

Comment: @FredrikLundin pretty cool. just tested this with `share`. Didn't know that. You probably should make your answer a bit clearer by adding the return type of `getCourses` to `: Observable<any>`, cause you have to subscribe to it to make it work.

Comment: True, but well adding `public` doesn't make a difference since it's the default, so i don't think it's on purpose in the question. anyway, thanks for the nice answer.

Comment: @FredrikLundin: Will it use same `baseUrl$` when I'll make another service call, instead of getCourse ?

Comment: @lexith : Will it use same baseUrl$ when I'll make another service call, instead of getCourse ?

Comment: @AmitKumar `baseUrl$` will only make one call, then the result will be re-used. A new call will only be made if you call `getJSON` directly. So any other method using the `baseUrl$` will share the same result

Comment: This solution doesn't work for latest Angular version.