# unable to fetch login user details in angular2 and firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, observable, angularfire2, angular-services

I am new to angular and firebase, let say I have a service like follow , i am using `angularfire2` to work with database

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, 
FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AuthService } from '../../../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class GroupsService {

user: User;

constructor(
 private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
 private db: AngularFireDatabase,
)  {

this.afAuth.authState.subscribe( ( loggedInUser ) => {
  this.user = {
    email: loggedInUser.email,
    id: loggedInUser.uid
  };

  console.log(this.user) //getting logged in user info correctly
});
}

getGroups():FirebaseListObservable<any[]>{
 console.log(this.user);  //unable to get logged in user
 return this.db.list('groups',{
   query : {
     orderByChild: 'createdBy/email',
     equalTo: this.user.email
   }
  });
}
```

on `getGroups()` method I am getting groups based on logged in user email address, In that function, on `console.log(this.user);` i am getting `undefined`,  can something please how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have a look at my answer here. Seems like a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/46484449/2521893

Comment: @FredrikLundin thanks for the answer, but I have doubt on share(), my app works even if I remove share() also, so can u please tell me whats the purpose of share()

Comment: By using share, the user ID will only be fetched once, and not on every request. Depends on how you want it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by info given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46484310/wait-for-subscription-in-constructor-of-a-service/46484449#46484449)

```
@Injectable()
export class GroupsService {

/**
* Observable for firebase user
*/
loggedInUser$: Observable<firebase.User>;


/**
* 
* @param authService 
* @param db 
*/
constructor(
private authService: AuthService,
private db: AngularFireDatabase,
) {

 this.loggedInUser$ = authService.user.share();
}

/**
* 
 */
getGroups():FirebaseListObservable<any>{

  return this.loggedInUser$.mergeMap( user => {

  let email = user.email;
  return this.db.list('groups', {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'createdBy/email',
      equalTo: email
    }
  }) 
  }) as FirebaseListObservable<any[]>
 }
 }
```